# What does $H_{*}(X)$ stand for?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I'm poring over Prof. Haynes Miller's lecture on Algebraic Topology, and I encountered this isomorphism: $H_{*}(X) \cong \tilde{H}_{*}(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, where $\tilde{H}_{*}(X)$ is the reduced homology on $X$. But I know that this is not true in general (this is true only for $n=0$). So this got me asking, does $H_{*}(X)$ stand for the $0$th singular homology, and so is $\tilde{H}_{*}(X)$? If not, what do they stand for, and why are they used instead of just $H_{0}(X)$?[image]

Comment: $H_\bullet$ is regarded as a graded ring, $\mathbb{Z}$ as a graded ring with $\mathbb{Z}$ in degree 0.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев but graded rings aren't in the picture yet. He defined graded Abelian group to be a sequence of Abelian groups indexed by the integers.

Comment: Well, ok, a group.

Comment: @АрсенийКряжев but it doesn't make sense. Direct sum is defined on Abelian groups, and, so far, nothing in the reference ever stated of $H_{*}$ having a group structure.

Comment: It‘s probably just a typo and he meant $H_0$.

Comment: You could also think of $H_*(X) = \bigoplus_{i} H_i(X)$, in which case the statement makes sense as a direct sum of ungraded groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some authors identify a module $M$ with the chain complex $\cdots \to 0 \to M \to 0 \to \cdots$ with $M$ in dimension $0$. See page $3$ of [this](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/MISC/TorExt.pdf) pdf or the [stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/010V), for instance. This is occasionally convenient, for reasons outlined in the linked pdf.

Under this convention, saying that $H_\bullet(X) \cong \widetilde{H}_\bullet(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ is on-the-nose correct, since $\mathbb{Z}$ is the chain complex that's $0$ in every dimension but $0$, where it's $\mathbb{Z}$. Indeed $H_n(X) \cong \widetilde{H}_n(X)$ in each dimension except $0$, where it's $H_0(X) \cong \widetilde{H}_0(X) \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, as commenters are mentioning, it could also be a typo. Without reading the notes (which you might want to link), it's hard to say.

Either way, it seems like *you* understand what's going on, which is worth more than complete correctness in the notes that you're reading!

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: On p.3 Miller says "We have just defined the singular chain complex $S_*(X)$ of a space $X$." This shows  that the index $*$ is used to denote graded abelian groups and chain complexes. On p.5 he says then that $H_*$ is a functor from spaces to graded abelian groups. He does not define explicitly define $\oplus$ for graded abelian groups, but it seems obvious to me that your interpretation is correct.

Comment: I think I understand your explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: Happy to help ^_^